# Set width and height jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a login page say login.jsp, If user logins successfully then user as forwarded to error.jsp. In that error.jsp i am showing error some text. But I am getting full screen with white background. I want the user should be able to see the previous page and on the top of thatpage, this error page should display with width 200 px and height 80 px. How to set width and height of jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an option for you would be to have a div in the page you want to append the error message to, then when an error occurs modify the contents or visibility of that div.

Just a thought.

Edit: Obviously if you did this, you could set the width and height in the css file.